# Change default variation value for the same product according to the category woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I'm working on a way to display default variations value for the SAME product according to the category he is.
For example, I sell a card with option blue & red.
When the user comes by the category ONE, I want the default value is blue.
If he comes by the category TWO, the value will be red.

I found a hook `woocommerce_product_default_attributes`, but I don't know how to use it .

**Note :** It seems that woocommerce recognize only one category per product even if your product is in two category.

---

**Example** *(edit)*:

I have a product **`P`**.
Product **`P`** is in two categories : `Cat 1` & `Cat 2`.
Also, product **`P`** has two variables : **`Blue`** & **`Red`**

When the user comes by **`Cat 1`**, I want the default value is **`Blue`**.
If he comes by **`Cat 2`**, the value will be **`Red`**.

**The answer code of @LoicTheAztech** *(below)* works, BUT:

> When I go to `Cat 1` or `Cat 2`, I can see that for Woocommerce, the product is only in `Cat 1`, even if we can access by both category.

So before everything, I need to solve the woocommerce issue.

Answer (score 2):

[**New updated answer HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49972781/3730754) with the replacement filter hook, as since WooCommerce 3, `get_variation_default_attributes()` method is replaced by **`get_default_attributes()`** and  `woocommerce_product_get_default_attributes` is the new related filter hook to be used.

---

Before WooCommerce 3, the filter hook **`woocommerce_product_default_attributes`** was located in **`get_variation_default_attributes()`** **deprecated method**, so it's not really the right hook to achieve what you want.

You can achieve your conditional function in **`woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form`** action hook, for example.

> **Notes:**
>
> - Product Attribute taxonomy always begin by 'pa_' + the attribute slug
> - You need to set in for variable products the default value for this attribute in the variation tab settings.

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', function(){
    global $product;

    // We EXIT if it's not a variable product
    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) return;

    ## DEFINE HERE the desired product attribute taxonomy
    $pa_attribute = 'pa_color';
    $default_attribute_for_variation = $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $pa_attribute );

    // We EXIT if Product Attribute Color is not set as variation usage
    if( empty( $default_attribute_for_variation ) ) return;

    // Get the array of default attributes
    $default_attributes = $product->get_default_attributes();

    // For product category 'ONE => Attribute "blue" slug value
    if( has_term( 'clothing', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )
        $default_attributes[$pa_attribute] = 'blue';

    // For product category 'TWO' => Attribute "blue" slug value
    elseif( has_term( 'TWO', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )
        $default_attributes[$pa_attribute] = 'red';

    else return; // If no product categories match we exit

    // If a product category match we set the default attribute
    $product->set_default_attributes( $default_attributes );
}, 80, 0 );
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, sorry for the late answer and thanks for the help ! I saw your code, but I realize one thing : Woocommerce doesn't allow two ways of category for the same product. In fact, the SAME product is in two category. When I tried your code, the product is recognised only in one..

Comment: @Efbi That is normal because is not possible to set 2 different default attributes values for the same product… So if Your product has categories 'ONE' and 'TWO' it will work for one only… So may be you have to update your Question as it's not enough explicit.

Comment: I totally change my question to be more clear ! Thanks for your patience

Comment: FYI: I asked at WooCommerce' GitHub repo if they could add back the `woocommerce_product_default_attributes` filter: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/19814

Comment: @nachtigall you can use `woocommerce_product_get_default_attributes` dynamic filter hook [**like in this new answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49972781/3730754) … As this is a dynamic hook based on new CRUDS setter and getter methods intoduced with Woocommerce 3, it will not be referenced by Automatic.

Comment: @nachtigall I hope that you didn't downvote the answers here, as I have spent some time and energy helping you, and this is just not fair… I agree with you about documentation, but Woocommerce/Automatic will never make any documentation for this hooks as they are like hundreds using new CRUD setters and getters methods…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec You did infact help me a lot and I am grateful for it, I did downvote so that the other answer (which is more useful) gets up. I did not want to show any disrespect. I reverted the downvote and upvoted again. Again, thank you, I really mean it! <3

Answer (score 2):

Since Woocommerce 3 you can use **`woocommerce_product_get_default_attributes`** filter hook… So your code for your 2 product categories will be something like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_default_attributes', 'filtering_product_get_default_attributes', 10, 2 );
function filtering_product_get_default_attributes( $default_attributes, $product ){
    // We EXIT if it's not a variable product
    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) return $default_attributes;

    ## --- YOUR SETTINGS (below) --- ##

    // The desired product attribute taxonomy (always start with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_color';

    $category1 = 'one' // The 1st product category (can be an ID, a slug or a name)
    $value1 = 'blue' // The corresponding desired attribute slug value for $category1

    $category2 = 'two' // The 2nd product category (can be an ID, a slug or a name)
    $value2 = 'red' // The corresponding desired attribute slug value for $category2

    ## --- The code --- ##

    // Get the default attribute used for variations for the defined taxonomy
    $default_attribute = $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $taxonomy );

    // We EXIT if define Product Attribute is not set for variation usage
    if( empty( $default_attribute ) ) return $default_attributes;

    // For product category slug 'one' => attribute slug value "blue"
    if( has_term( 'one', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )
        $default_attributes[$taxonomy] = 'blue';

    // For product category slug 'two' => attribute slug value "red"
    elseif( has_term( 'two', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) )
        $default_attributes[$taxonomy] = 'red';

    else return $default_attributes; // If no product categories match we exit

    return $default_attributes; // Always return the values in a filter hook
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Not tested yet, but it should work.

**Explanations:**

> Since Woocommerce 3 and new introduced CRUDS setter methods, when a method is using `get_prop()` `WC_Data` method, a dynamic hook based on the object type and the method name can be used *(essentially for frontend: "view" context)*…

**See [this line](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b2e4052e3bcc87dd100e70d25f59dc76c413f2a3/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-data.php#L600-L623) `$value = apply_filters( $this->get_hook_prefix() . $prop, $value, $this );` in**

**and [this line](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b2e4052e3bcc87dd100e70d25f59dc76c413f2a3/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-data.php#L590-L598)`return 'woocommerce_' . $this->object_type . '_get_';` in**

So **the filter hook is dynamically made** this way  *(where `$this->object_type` is equal to `'product'`)*:

```
'woocommerce_' . $this->object_type . '_get_' . 'default_attributes'
```

with 2 arguments:

- `$attributes` *(the property value that replace `$value`)*
- `$product` *(the class instance object that replace `$this`)*…

---

See it on [Woocommerce Github closed and solved issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/19814)

Comment: @Luiggity see this new answer that solve the problem…