# change programmly default product variation image on "/shop" archives - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I really tried to search other related topics here no success.
I have woocommerce website, which have 100 products, each of them have 11 variants, on shop, when i filter them by attribute - model, 
I get the products which have variant, so far so good

BUT, I need it the products will set default variant to that chosen filter, because I have different picture each variant, when someone filter by attribute on my website, he expect to see the specific model on all products.

I'm selling cases, which every product fit about 11 different devices, and almost each of them have different products image.

thanks for helpers.

Again, I tried here looking for other topics, and many of functions to my child-theme function php files, with modifications, but none of them helped me.

Edit: to be Clear, i Already Have Default Values on Model Attribure, 
BUT, that defualt Attribute value need to be change(for all displayed products) **everytime user filter to deffrent attribute Value** (change Model )
thats what im trying to do: [(this is the source before i changed the code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073328/change-default-variation-value-for-the-same-product-according-to-the-category-wo)

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_default_attributes', 'filtering_product_get_default_attributes', 10, 2 );
function filtering_product_get_default_attributes( $default_attributes, $product ){
    // We EXIT if it's not a variable product
    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) return $default_attributes;

    ## --- YOUR SETTINGS (below) --- ##

    // The desired product attribute taxonomy (always start with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_model';

    ## --- The code --- ##
    // Get the attribute used for filer from URL
  $Model = $_GET['pa_model'];
     
    $default_attribute = $product->get_variation_default_attribute( $taxonomy );

    // We EXIT if define Product Attribute is not set for variation usage
    if( empty( $default_attribute ) ) return $default_attributes;
 $default_attributes[$taxonomy] = $Model;
    return $default_attributes; // Always return the values in a filter hook
}
```

Edit :
i will explain that issue again: 
on shop page, where i can see grid of products, **the image i set for variations is not changed when i filter the results of products by attribute**
.
while on single product page, its works fine (change variation will change products image too)

again - thanks for helpers

Comment: nope its NOT. you didnt understood me well
i have already defualt variant, BUT i need to change it every time user choose diffrent attribute value

Comment: now you do understand?

Comment: if yoiu really want to help dont judge, i will post my code attemp

Comment: here is someone had kind of same issue, noone helped here also
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48720757/changing-product-image-according-to-color-variations-woocommerce-shop-page